# Horizontal Swipe Cards effect - Android

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, horizontal-scrolling, android-cardview, horizontallist

I am trying to find a way to create a horizontal card swipe effect to display some fragments, like in the image attached. I was looking for an alternative, the closest thing I have found was the CardView layout, but this is vertical only.

Could someone suggest a way to get this nice layout working?

[image]

Comment: Hi, anything new? I would like to create the same.

Comment: hi @DonovanCharpin. I have solved the issue using ViewPager. It has everything you need, but there will be things that needs some hacking. But I am happy with the results. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Edmond. If you have some code in an opensource repo, feel free to share it :)

Comment: Looking for the same. Have you open sourced it. Or can you @EdmondTamas

Comment: @EdmondTamas Did you finally succeed in getting any library?